# Suppress scientific notation on axis label without using setOffset

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I am plotting some time series data with the time being GPS time. I'd like the ticks on my x-axis to be seconds relative to a reference time. So the ticks should be in the range [-100, 100], rather than e.g. [1390585610, 1390585810] (the current GPS time as I write this). I can get this behavior by writing:

```
axs[1].ticklabel_format(axis = 'x', useOffset = central_time, style = 'plain')
```

but this produces a small label to the bottom right of the x-axis reading "+1.390585710e9", which I don't want to be displayed. Is there a way to suppress the scientific notation but keep my desired x-axis ticking.

Here's an example of the current behavior and the code used to make it:
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = [1390585610, 1390585660, 1390585710, 1390585760, 1390585810]
ys = [-1, 0, 1, 0 , -1]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)
axs.plot(xs, ys)
axs.ticklabel_format(axis = 'x', useOffset = 1390585710, style = 'plain')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77901702/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just subtract the offset manually for the plotter and forgo the `useOffset` parameter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.array([1390585610, 1390585660, 1390585710, 1390585760, 1390585810])
ys = [-1, 0, 1, 0 , -1]
offset = 1390585710

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)
axs.plot(xs-offset, ys)
axs.ticklabel_format(axis = 'x', style = 'plain')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works, of course. Not sure why I didn't think of this :)